Sprinklers not turning on
I recently replaced my sprinkler valves as my old ones were leaking and none of my zones were turning on. Even after replacing them none of my sprinklers turn on. Checked my controller and the solenoids and both have power. What else should I do to diagnose the issue? Also tried to turn the valves on manually and still no water.

if they do not turn on manually, the main supply water line needs attention

I’ve checked that and all looks good and water is getting to the valves.

Is the controller applying appropriate power to the solenoids?

It is. I check both at the controller and solenoids with a multimeter

the valve turns on, but no or low water pressure

Correct. I am assuming there may be a crack somewhere. That’s all I can think of that would cause this.
